# Handling Hover over menu's using Cypress

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress

I recently stumbled upon the e2e tool - [Cypress.io](https://www.cypress.io/). I'm currently doing a POC for the firm I work with for e2e testing of a react app. It has a hover over menu like most of the web apps have now.

An example :

URL : [Fmovies](https://fmovies.pe/)

I was trying to click a menu item from this hover over but the test fails saying that the `display` is set to `none`.

In Selenium, we use the `moveElement` approach to go to this element, and then do whatever we need to do. However, I'm failing to do so using Cypress.

Considering the current menu, I wrote this

```
it('goes to specific element in Genre',()=>{
        cy.get('#menu').within(()=>{
            cy.get('ul').within(()=>{
                cy.contains('Family').click();
            });
        });
    });
```

Error :
[image: Error]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cypress has a unique workflow that is based around baking in as many tests as possible into its default behavior. Before it simulates the click on the element containing "Family", it [checks for actionability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#Actionability). This is a built in test that will fail if the element is hidden, `display:none`(that's the case here), size 0,0, etc. Only after it passes that test will it simulate the action on the element containing 'Family'.

You can override the actionability check by using `.click({force:true})`, but then you lose the guarantee that the user would actually be able to find and click on the element.

The proper way to do this test is to trigger the dropdown menu so that the element becomes visible, and then do the click. Here's what you would do if you wanted to find the "Genre" menu item, reveal the dropdown menu, and click the "Family" item:

```
describe('Hover Menu',()=>{
    it('can click on a genre sub-menu item',()=>{
        cy.get('#menu').contains('Genre').next('.sub-menu').then($el=>{
            cy.wrap($el).invoke('show')
            cy.wrap($el).contains('Family').click()
        })
    })
})
```

Here, `show` is a jQuery method that modifies CSS properties to make the element visible.

`cy.wrap($el)` turns a jQuery element into a Cypress Chainer, which you can then call Cypress commands on.

Comment: Well, that is what I was trying to achieve. Trigger the drop down menu and then click on the link.

Comment: @demouser123 see my updated answer, it should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the solution which worked perfectly for me. However, I am not clear on what is going on here & the docs, while amazingly helpful, didn't clarify for me. For example, why do we `wrap` `$el`, which is an object? The docs say that `invoke` calls a function, however, where is `show` coming from? Many thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer for us.