# Hover over button using Cypress

Tags: hover, cypress

I'm trying to hover over a button in Cypress and for that I've tried to use trigger('mouseover') but it is not working for me. Any suggestions?

```
  it('hovering over button', () => {
cy.visit("http://www.qaclickacademy.com/practice.php");
cy.get('#mousehover').trigger('mouseover'); })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling Hover over menu's using Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852219/handling-hover-over-menus-using-cypress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a workaround for this. With the use of Invoke() method in my code I was able to hover over a button.

```
  it('hovering over button', () => {
  cy.visit("http://www.qaclickacademy.com/practice.php");
  cy.get('.mouse-hover-content').should('be.hidden').invoke('show');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above helped me to find the solution for me:

```
cy.get('.mouse-hover-content')
  .should('be.hidden')
  .invoke('css', 'visibility', 'visible')
```

Comment: According to the linked answer, ***`show()` is a jQuery method that modifies CSS properties to make the element visible***. Did `invoke('show')` not work for you?

Comment: No, just `invoke('show')` does not work for me