# Unable to mouseover on a menu option which is covered by another element

Tags: cypress

I have a menu option on a website on which I am unable to mouseover as it throws an error

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.trigger() failed because this element:

<span class="AspNet-Menu-NonLink tab1">Manage ...</span>

is being covered by another element:

<div id="LogoLink" class="LogoLink">...</div>
```

The DOM structure is like this

[image]

I have removed that LogoLink element but still the mouseover is not happening. I also tried to click the element but no luck. Cypress is searching element every time, but cannot perform mouseover/click (may be its performing thats why no error is getting displayed after removing the LogoLink element). Using selenium, I am able to perform click using JavaScript Executor and sub menu gets opened.

I have also followed the post [Handling Hover over menu's using Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852219/handling-hover-over-menus-using-cypress) but the solution provided in the post does not work for me.

Please can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try force a click?
cy.get('button').click({force:true})